# Enforce a line-break inside \lstinline

Tags: listings, line-breaking, sourcecode

I use `\lstinline{foo}` from the `listings` package to set pieces of code in regular text. To get automatic line-breaks I use the following options:

```
\lstset{
 breaklines=true,
 breakatwhitespace=true,
 breakindent=2ex,
 postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookrightarrow\space}}
}
```

Sometime code fragments have to go into rather narrow table cells and the automatic line breaks just don't look very nice.

Is there any way to tell `\lstinline` (and `lstlisting`) where to insert line-breaks without actually putting them into the LaTeX source literally? If I do hard code them this will influence line numbers (in `lstlisting`s) and also the line continuation symbol and indentation will be missing.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: This may or may not be somewhat related, depending on your requirements and flexibility: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124435/customised-counter-macro-in-fancyvrb/124444#124444

Answer (score 8):

You can certainly escape into LaTeX and force a break manually, for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
 breaklines        = true,
 breakatwhitespace = true,
 breakindent       = 2ex,
 escapechar        = *,
 numbers           = left
}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
Some text
Some more text Some more text Some more text Some more text
Some more text Some more text *\break* Some more text Some more text
Final text
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Whether this is what is required I'm not 100% sure: telling `listings` where to break without adding anything to the source seems extremely difficult to imagine.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need this once and don't want to declare it with \lstset you can set breaklines to true directly in lstinline.

```
\lstinline[breaklines=true]|[this is a very long command]|
```

Comment: The OP already has `breaklines` in their code. The question is more about how to influence this automatic line-breaking.